# Indesign Document to Word Template

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, document-setup, template

I have created a document template in indesign. I want to use it as background in Word. I've been trying to set it as a background image in Word but it keeps tiling the image or over stretching it. Both the InDesign file and Word Document are set up as a4.

Anyone got any ideas on how I could work round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in Word, but I have had to do this exact thing before. What I've done:

1) Export the InDesign layout as a .jpg (In my experience, Word seems to like that format best when importing a file)

2) In your Word doc, make sure your document margins are set to 0 on all sides.
[image]

3) Insert the file, and make sure it's actually placed at 100% (you can check under Format > Picture (click on the "Size" tab on the left of the dialog box)
[image]

4) If your original image isn't exactly A4 size, and you need to center it on your page in Word, you can tweak the margins to get it where you want:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ciaran, I would recommend you add the image to the header/footer. You will need to give it a fixed position and change the wrap properties to 'behind text'. You will all so need to rescale to A4 and position at 0 from page. I don't recommend ever changing margins to 0 as you will get major problems if/when you try to print.

David

P.S. I like to think I am an expert in Word!